# Update error message contradicted by settings

Tags: networking, updates

Opening Ubuntu Software I get a banner warning, "Automatic Updates Paused". When I click the [Find Out More] button (top right) I get this pop-up:
[image]

When I click [Open Network Settings] nothing happens.

Going through Settings > Wi-Fi > (router) settings confirms my connection is not metered:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: weyell, try getting  a better internet plan.  It says you are connected with the internet and have the *potential* to get 144 mb/s, but your internet plan says no as you have reached your limit.  At least, that's what it looks like.

Comment: Welcome to the Third World, aka Britain. That line actually means I have a download of 144Mbps at 2.5GHz. "Potentially" I can get >4G (no 5G here).
However, the point is the connection is NOT metered despite the error message.